# Download CMIS renditions only if they have changed

Tags: cmis

Detecting whether a CMIS document has changed without downloading it is [easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190247/most-efficient-way-to-detect-changes-of-a-remote-cmis-repository) thanks to ChangeLog and metadata.

But how about renditions?

Whenever a document is modified I re-download the renditions, but it is not enough to be sure I have the current ones:

1. I am not sure how long it takes the server to generate renditions. Maybe the server is very slow, or only generates renditions at night.
2. Renditions might change without the original document being changed, for instance after a modification of the server's rendition parameters or after a software update.

If I understand the [CMIS 1.1 specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/errata01/os/CMIS-v1.1-errata01-os-complete.html#x1-3820006) correctly, I can get this metadata about a rendition without downloading it:

- href:
  URI to the rendition content stream
- type:
  The Media Type of the rendition
- cmisra:renditionKind:
  The Rendition Kind for the rendition

The following attributes MAY be included:

- title:
  The ﬁlename (or name property if object) of rendition
- length:
  The length of the rendition in bytes

No creation timestamp nor version nor reference to the original's version. Am I out of luck, with nothing to do but download the rendition to see whether it has changed or not?

Answer (score 0):

The server shouldn't offer outdated renditions. If a rendition doesn't match the main content anymore, for whatever reason, it should (temporarily) disappear from the list of renditions. This way, clients always only get current renditions.